# "Letter 'A' with multiple lines" icon appears after taking a screenshot

Tags: huawei, screenshots, editing

I noticed an icon (seen on the attached image) on the Edit screen that appears after taking a screenshot on my Honor Android phone.

[image]

<sup>Image resized. Click for full size</sup>

I'm unsure of its functionality and couldn't find any information in the user manual or online resources.

Is this icon a feature of Android in general, or is it specific to Honor devices? Any insights would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. I believe it's not a feature of Android in general since the manufacturer can also customize the screenshot editor; both screenshot editors on Pixel 3a and Galaxy M12 look totally different compared to this screenshot.

Comment: My Sansung Note 20 shows it

Answer (score 3):

Its on my Android Note 20 as well. After playing with it, it appears after a screenshot.

If you press it, it highlights all the text on the screen. If you touch any text,  it is copied to the clipboard.

I  guess  the thought is that you can find a caption for the screen shot that you have just made, on the screen.

Comment: Problem is that on my Honor 50 phone it doesn't do anything useful :(
Dunno why